# Upgrade Ruby on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How does ruby version get set and updated on ELB?

I've been using `ruby 2.2.2` on our qa and staging env's for about 8 months now. I just setup our production env Monday and it wouldn't deploy as it said ruby was set to 2.2.3 and my gemfile said 2.2.2. I updated and redeployed and everything seemed to be fine.

I came back to the qa/staging env's and can't get it to update to ruby 2.2.3. Kept saying ruby version is 2.2.2 and Gemfile is 2.2.3

I upgraded (through elb ui):

`64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v1.3.1 running Ruby 2.2 (Passenger Standalone)` to

`64bit Amazon Linux 2015.09 v2.0.6 running Ruby 2.2 (Passenger Standalone)`

Now it says `Your Ruby version is 2.2.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.2`. There has to be an easier way to do this.

Comment: To clarify, you want to use Ruby 2.2.3 in all environments, correct? Have you specified ruby 2.2.3 in your gem file? See http://bundler.io/v1.3/gemfile_ruby.html

Comment: set ruby version on your Gemfile as 2.2.3 and delete your Gemfile.lock file. run bundle install locally , commit your code and deploy.

Comment: Correct, we were using 2.2.2 on qa and stag, when I setup the new prod env elb wanted to use 2.2.3 so I set that in the Gemfile and deployed and it worked on prod. But after merging that in to qa branch it wouldn't deploy. I'll try whacking the .lock file and re-deploying.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since you want to update both the platform and the version label at the same time you can always use the UpdateEnvironment API specifying both the solution stack name and version label parameters.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/api/API_UpdateEnvironment.html

You can use the aws cli or sdk to do this.

#### Step-By-Step as described by @Scott:

- Update Gemfile to match ruby version on new platform
- Zip up codebase (including .elasticbeanstalk and .ebextensions),
- Upload to elb through application versions (AWS Console -> EB -> All applications -> Application Versions)
- Run `aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --environment-name "corresponding_env_name" --solution-stack-name "64bit Amazon Linux 2015.09 v2.0.6 running Ruby 2.2 (Passenger Standalone)" --version-label "zip_name_you_uploaded"`
- Everything deployed correctly
- Drink some beer.

Comment: Don't they always need to be done at the same time if the platform version also bumped it's ruby version? I'll check out the UpdateEnv API for my staging update, as I ended up rebuilding the env for qa. Thanks!

Comment: I see your usecase but if you can lock to something like 2.2.x in your Gemfile, that would work too.

Comment: How do I get the version label if I can't push the code until the configuration has been updated?

Comment: You can use CreateApplicationVersion API http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/api/API_CreateApplicationVersion.html or you can use the "Upload and Deploy" button on the console and then just upload a new version on the application versions page.

Comment: ok, I think you've got me on the right track now. I'll comment tomorrow and post the actual command I used for future reference if it works on my staging env. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, so here is what I did (feel free to add this to your answer for reference). Updated Gemfile to match ruby version on new platform, zipped up codebase (including .elasticbeanstalk and .ebextensions), uploaded to elb through application versions, ran `aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --environment-name "corresponding_env_name" --solution-stack-name "64bit Amazon Linux 2015.09 v2.0.6 running Ruby 2.2 (Passenger Standalone)" --version-label "zip_name_you_uploaded"` everything deployed correctly and now i'm gonna drink some beer. Thanks Rohit!

Comment: Fyi the command to print the full list of EB solution stack names is: `aws elasticbeanstalk list-available-solution-stacks`

Comment: I was using **eb cli** to deploy with `eb deploy`, and was bumping into this problem after updating the platform from **Ruby 3.0 Amazon Linux 2/3.4.4** to **Ruby 3.0 Amazon Linux 2/3.4.6**, which upgraded **Ruby 3.0.3 -> 3.0.4**. What solved for me was deploying via zip file generated via `git archive -v -o myapp.zip --format=zip HEAD`.

Answer (score 2):

I found a different approach to this problem.

The way I made it work is similar to the comment above with a small change.

Steps I did:

1. Launched a completely new environment on beanstalk running the ruby version that I need, 2.3 (in my case I needed an update from Ruby 2.2 to Ruby 2.3) - used the sample application for faster and easier launch.
2. SSH-ed into the new instance and installed all dependencies that my application needs (packages, dev tools etc.) - you can also do these in the .ebextensions directory
3. Created a custom AMI from the instance running ruby 2.3 with everything installed
4. Used the same command that Rohit posted but with some tweeks:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --region "REGION" --environment-name "ENV_NAME" --solution-stack-name "64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.8.1 running Ruby 2.3 (Puma)" --option-settings Namespace=aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration,OptionName=ImageId,Value="ami- 
xxxxxxxx"
```

The **AMI option-settings** was key for me, as this helped me the AMI with ruby 2.3.7 installed to be used for launching the new instance on the existing environment.
Previously just hitting [@Rohit Banga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/161628/rohit-banga) suggested command failed on every try.

Not to forget, I have also specified the ruby version "2.3.7" in my Gemfile as well.