# How to fix "Your Ruby version is 2.5.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.1" deploying the AWS eb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

**Issue:** I am having issues deploying app to AWS EB and every remedy I have found on SO and google have not helped my situation.

I installed the AWS EB command line and looking to deploy an app I have built to there but i keep getting this error after attempts to resolve it:

```
ERROR   [Instance: i-065ec77b2c530362b] Command failed on instance. Return code: 18 Output: (TRUNCATED)...g: the running version of Bundler (1.16.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.17.2). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
Your Ruby version is 2.5.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.1. 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_bundle_install.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
2018-12-21 08:51:28    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
```

The app was initially built with 2.5.1 but I switched it to 2.5.3 today so I can put it onto AWS.  (I have both of these ruby versions with rbenv)

**I have done:**

- Set `ruby '2.5.3'` in Gemfile
- `bundle update`
- `bundle install`
- `gem install bundler`
- `gem update bundler`
- deleted gem lock file and `bundle update`d
- `./bin/spring stop` (spring not running)

`ruby -v`  is `ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x86_64-linux]`
(this is local only, I have rbenv global set to 2.5.1, but I don't believe this is an issue as the error states  i's the gemfile)

I have done `rbenv rehash` after updating or installing bundle

`bundle update --ruby`

Gemfile.lock shows 2.5.3

**bundle env shows:**

````
RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.5.3p105

BUNDLED WITH
   1.17.2
```
````

**My entire Gemfile - just in case this may help for something:**

```
gem 'dotenv-rails', groups: [:development, :test]

source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.3'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.1'

gem 'stripe'
gem 'stripe_event'
gem 'pry'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
# gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'pg'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem "chartkick"
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'

gem 'api-pagination', '~> 4.1', '>= 4.1.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.6'
gem 'groupdate'
gem 'blazer'    
gem 'ahoy_matey'    
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancancan', '~> 2.0'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.0'
gem 'carrierwave-aws'
gem 'carrierwave-ffmpeg'
gem 'carrierwave-video'

gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.1.3'
gem 'sprockets-rails', :require => 'sprockets/railtie'
gem 'sprockets'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'

  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

**More info:**

- `rbenv local`: 2.5.3
- `rbenv global`: 2.5.1
- `bundle exec which ruby`: /home/bob/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/ruby
- `rbenv versions`:
  system
  2.5.1

  2.5.3 (set by /home/bob/Apps/uploader-master-side-3/.ruby-version)
- `bundler -v`: Bundler version 1.17.2
- `bundle platform --ruby`: ruby 2.5.3p105
- `which ruby`: /home/bob/.rbenv/shims/ruby
- `rails c`:

  Running via Spring preloader in process 5437
  Loading development environment (Rails 5.2.2)
  irb(main):001:0>
- `which gem`: /home/bob/.rbenv/shims/gem
- `rbenv which gem`: /home/bob/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/gem
- `which -a gem`:
  /home/bob/.rbenv/shims/gem
  /usr/bin/gem
- `rbenv which bundle`: /home/bob/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/bundle
- `echo $PATH`: /home/bob/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/home/bob/.rbenv/shims:/home/bob/.rbenv/bin:/home/bob/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
- `ruby-build --version`: ruby-build 20181106-14-g1ec9abd

**When I run server:**

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.2 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.5.3-p105), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

Thank you for your time and reading this and your help!!!

NAIL IN THE COFFIN:

I just took the copy of my app i created before updating to the new ruby and tried to deploy it and got this:

```
Your Ruby version is 2.5.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.1. 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_bundle_install.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
2018-12-21 11:04:39    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
```

.....this is which 2.5.1 set globally and locally

What other options do I have? Delete and re install rbenv? Make a new app and copy everything over except the gemfile? I'm out of options and ideas it seems like

**UPDATE:**

I had no clue that AWS EB was based off my git commits and i never updated them before trying... ( wow ) and now i don't receive the ruby version error...

**So now i don't get the version error but I do get this error:**

```
2018-12-21 22:50:56    ERROR   [Instance: i-00ae954ad2b716b2a] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...lizers/carrierwave.rb:1:in `<main>'
/var/app/ondeck/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace). 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/11_asset_compilation.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
2018-12-21 22:50:56    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2018-12-21 22:51:58    ERROR   Create environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.
```

Since this error is different from the original question, I have created a new one here: [Deploying with AWWS EB but with erors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53891770/deploying-with-awws-eb-but-with-erors)

Comment: Really obvious thing to check, sorry, but ... Are you *sure* that the updated `Gemfile` is deployed to AWS? Did you commit and push the right branch?

Comment: Can you try to use `.ruby-version` file and remove it from `Gemfile`?

Comment: @TomLord I updated everything to new Ruby before anything.  then went ahead   "eb init", no codecommit, then "eb create", choose default environment name, default DNS CNAME prefix, choose default Application load balance type, then it starts creating

Comment: @Mauro are you saying to delete .ruby-version file and that's it? Or something afterwards?  Can you elaborate more on that?

Comment: @TomLord I updated my OP - you were right.  I didn't know it was dependent on Git.  I figured it would just take the local app and go (I'm new to deploying to the internet).. I linked a new question with my most recent error though.  I would be obliged if you would read into it

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem after upgrading the platform from **Ruby 3.0 Amazon Linux 2/3.4.4** to **Ruby 3.0 Amazon Linux 2/3.4.6**, which upgrades **Ruby 3.0.3 -> 3.0.4**

I was using `eb cli` to deploy with, `eb deploy`, but what solve the issue was deploying via uploading a zip file directly in AWS Elastic Beanstalk console, in **Elastic Beanstalk > Applications > your-app > Application versions**.

The zip file was generated with `git archive -v -o myapp.zip --format=zip HEAD`, according to [AWS manual](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/applications-sourcebundle.html).

I am replying here because this was the first SO link on Google, but this was the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35203225/upgrade-ruby-on-elastic-beanstalk) that helped me.