# Change platform on Elastic Beanstalk from PHP to Node.js

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to change the platform on an existing Elastic Beanstalk instance from PHP 7 to Node.js. However, via the AWS Dashboard, I can only change/upgrade the version of PHP.

Is it currently possible to make this change through the dashboard or command line?

Comment: I believe you'll need to create a new environment to change the platform.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think you can use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36599241/2810489):

```
aws elasticbeanstalk list-available-solution-stacks

aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --solution-stack-name "64bit Amazon Linux 2017.09 v4.4.4 running Node.js" --environment-name "example-env" --region "eu-west-1"
```