# Update AWS Elastic Beanstalk solution stack name

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Cloudformation template with the following Elastic Beanstalk environment:

```
Resources:
  BeanstalkEnvironment1:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: Application1
      Description: ignored
      EnvironmentName: Environment1'
      SolutionStackName: '64bit Amazon Linux 2017.03 v2.5.0 running Python 3.4'
```

My main goal is to update the environment's Python version from 3.4 to 3.6. I was able to update the solution stack name with the following command (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36599241))

```
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --solution-stack-name "64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.7.6 running Python 3.6" --environment-name "Environment1"
```

However, I cannot do subsequent updates using the existing template if I update it to the new solution stack name, because I get "[Cannot update a stack when a custom-named resource requires replacing](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-custom-name/)". It works if I keep the original one, but I would like to keep the running platform in sync with the template.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I get the same problem.  This appears to be a limitation of Elastic Beanstalk and CloudFormation.  In the docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk-environment.html) an update to `SolutionStackName` shows as `Update requires: Replacement`.

If you just change the `EnvironmentName` every time you change `SolutionStackName` it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation note of SolutionStackName:

> Note: If you specify SolutionStackName, don't specify PlatformArn or
> TemplateName.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).